# AWS EC2 Immediate Scaling Up?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I have a web service running on several EC2 boxes.  Based on the Cloudwatch latency metric, I'd like to scale up additional boxes.  But, given that it takes several minutes to spin up an EC2 from an AMI (with startup code to download the latest application JAR and apply OS patches), is there a way to have a "cold" server that could instantly be turned on/off?

Answer (score 1):

Not by using AutoScaling. At least not, instant in the way you describe. You could make it much faster however, by making your own modified AMI image where you place the JAR and the latest OS patches. These AMI's can be generated as part of your build pipeline. In that case, your only real wait time is for the OS and services to start, similar to a "cold" server.

[Packer](https://www.packer.io/) is a tool commonly used for such use cases.

Alternatively, you can mange it yourself, by having servers switched off, and start them by writing some custom Lambda scripts that gets triggered by Cloudwatch alerts. But since stopped servers aren't exactly free either, i would recommend against that for cost reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Before you venture into the journey of auto scaling your infrastructure and spending time/effort.  Perhaps you should do a little bit of analysis on the traffic pattern day over day, week over week and month over month and see if it's even necessary? Try answering some of these questions.

1. What was the highest traffic ever your app handled, How did the servers fare given the traffic? How was the user response time?
2. When does your traffic ramp up or hit peak? Some apps get traffic during business hours while others in the evening.
3. What is your current throughput? For example, you can handle 1k requests/min and two EC2 hosts are averaging 20% CPU. if the requests triple to 3k requests/min are you able to see around 60% - 70% avg cpu? this is a good indication that your app usage is fairly predictable can scale linearly by adding more hosts. But if you've never seen traffic burst like that no point over provisioning.

Unless you have a Zynga like application where you can see large number traffic at once perhaps better understanding your traffic pattern and throwing in an additional host as insurance could be helpful. I'm making these assumptions as I don't know the nature of your business.

If you do want to auto scale anyway, one solution would be to containerize your application with Docker or create your own AMI like others have suggested. Still it will take few minutes to boot them up. Next option is the keep hosts on standby but and add those to your load balancers using scripts ( or lambda functions) that watches metrics you define (I'm assuming your app is running behind load balancers).

Good luck.